# How to prevent IPython from activate to the cell below after running a cell?

Tags: ipython

After running a code in given cell, `IPython` goes down to the next cell below and activate it.

How to set IPython so that it "stays" in the same cell after code is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Enter, instead of Shift+Enter